# setting language before setContentView results in unending loop

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, multilingual, android-preferences

I have a fragment with settings of an app that saves the user selected mode and language
( a bit of code:

```kotlin
binding.languageButton.setOnClickListener{
        builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.setLanguage))
        builder.setItems(langArray) { _, which ->
            
            val sharedPref = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            sharedPref.putString("LANGUAGE", langArray[which]).apply()
            checkUserPreferences()

            changeLanguage(langArray[which])
            binding.languageButton.text = langArray[which]
        }
        builder.create()
        builder.show()
    }
}

private fun changeLanguage(language: String) {
    if(language != binding.languageButton.text.toString()){
        val local = Locale(language)
        val dm =  resources.displayMetrics
        val con = resources.configuration
        con.locale = local
        resources.updateConfiguration(con, dm)
        val refresh = Intent(
                requireContext(),
                MainActivity::class.java
        )
        refresh.putExtra(binding.languageButton.text.toString(), language)
        startActivity(refresh)
    }
}
```

and that part (as mentioned) saves mode and selected language to sharedPreferences that I later want to use in mainActivity and other fragments, and I've put in MainActivity:

```kotlin
private fun loadPreferences(){
    val preferences = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
    Log.i(TAG, preferences.getString("LANGUAGE", "eng").toString())
    Log.i(TAG, preferences.getInt("MODE", 1).toString())
    val local = Locale(preferences.getString("LANGUAGE", "eng").toString())
    val dm =  resources.displayMetrics
    val con = resources.configuration
    con.locale = local
    resources.updateConfiguration(con, dm)
    val refresh = Intent(
            this.baseContext,
            MainActivity::class.java
    )
    refresh.putExtra(preferences.getString("LANGUAGE", "eng").toString(),
            preferences.getString("LANGUAGE", "eng"))
    startActivity(refresh)
}
```

and this is referenced in:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // TODO: IT'S THE ONE
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
        private const val CHANNEL_ID = "plantz_app_channel_01"
        private const val notificationId = 909
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        loadPreferences()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

// ...
```

and after running the app It only shows the app logo and logs sharedPreferences but the app doesn't go any further, I've tried to tweak with it for a bit but It hasn't done much, any ideas what should I change to make it work?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This infinity loop happens because when the MainActivity is going to be opened you call **loadPreferences()** in onCreate method where you open a new instance of MainActivity from there.
So the infinity loop goes like below:

1. onCreate() method of MainActivity is called
2. loadPreferences() method is called
3. in loadPreferences() after you have set the language from SharedPreferences you start a new instance of your MainActivity which redirects you back to step 1.

To avoid this infinity loop remove the below lines from your **loadPreferences()** method:

```
val refresh = Intent(this.baseContext,MainActivity::class.java)
refresh.putExtra(preferences.getString("LANGUAGE", "eng").toString(), preferences.getString("LANGUAGE", "eng"))
startActivity(refresh)
```